# spring-boot running with idea,build with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-boot

I create a spring-boot project with idea,but when I run the main class,it alway wrong.but when I run the main class with eclipse ,it will not wrong.I cannot understand.below is my configuration.
main class:

```
    package com.xiaojiuwo;


import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
//import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MultiPartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.xiaojiuwo.support.interceptor.PermissionInterceptor;
import com.xiaojiuwo.support.EnumAwareConvertUtilsBean;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Transactional
@EnableJpaAuditing
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public Filter applicationContextIdFilter(ApplicationContext context) {
            CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            return filter;
        }
    }       

    @Value("${spring.datasource.name:testdb}")
    private String name = "testdb";

    @Bean
    public PermissionInterceptor permissionInterceptor() {
        return new PermissionInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(permissionInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("50000000KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("50000000KB");

        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeanUtilsBean.setInstance(new BeanUtilsBean(new EnumAwareConvertUtilsBean()));

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(true); 
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

maven pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.xiaojiuwo</groupId>
  <artifactId>BI</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>BI</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.32</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <classifier>jdk15</classifier><!--指定jdk版本-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

the error report:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=GBK -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:\idea14_workspace\BI\target\classes;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-core\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.8.1\aspectjrt-1.8.1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.1\aspectjweaver-1.8.1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-context-support\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-context\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-test\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-test-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\objenesis\objenesis\1.0\objenesis-1.0.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-test\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring4\2.1.3.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\2.1.3.RELEASE\thymeleaf-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\ognl\ognl\3.0.6\ognl-3.0.6.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.0\unbescape-1.0.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\1.2.5\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.2.5.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.13\snakeyaml-1.13.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.7\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.7\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.7\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.2\logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.2\logback-core-1.1.2.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.2\commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.3.3\jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.3.3\jackson-annotations-2.3.3.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.3.3\jackson-core-2.3.3.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-web\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.32\mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\7.0.54\tomcat-jdbc-7.0.54.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\7.0.54\tomcat-juli-7.0.54.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.3.5.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging-annotations\1.2.0.Beta1\jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.5.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\jboss\jandex\1.1.0.Final\jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.1-GA\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.6.2.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.8.2.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.0.3.Final\hibernate-validator-5.0.3.Final.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.1.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.0.0\classmate-1.0.0.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\net\sf\json-lib\json-lib\2.4\json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\net\sf\ezmorph\ezmorph\1.0.6\ezmorph-1.0.6.jar;D:\Maven_repo2.5\com\alibaba\druid\1.0.12\druid-1.0.12.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\jconsole.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\lib\tools.jar;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.xiaojiuwo.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.5.RELEASE)

2015-05-05 19:44:56.289  INFO 6180 --- [           main] com.xiaojiuwo.Application                : Starting Application on pek1-fil-874-PC with PID 6180 (D:\idea14_workspace\BI\target\classes started by zhanghengqiang in D:\idea14_workspace\BI)
2015-05-05 19:44:56.347  INFO 6180 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@191ac0df: startup date [Tue May 05 19:44:56 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:307)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:235)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at com.xiaojiuwo.Application.main(Application.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 25 more
2015-05-05 19:44:56.385  INFO 6180 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@191ac0df: startup date [Tue May 05 19:44:56 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-05-05 19:44:56.390  WARN 6180 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@191ac0df: startup date [Tue May 05 19:44:56 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:809)

2015-05-05 19:44:56.390  WARN 6180 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@191ac0df: startup date [Tue May 05 19:44:56 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:809)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `but when I run the main class,it alway wrong.but when I run the main class with eclipse ,it will not wrong.` What are you trying to say?

Comment: Probably because you excluded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.

Comment: @Steve  thanks steve.but I add the dependency below that.                                    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: You flagged it as `provided`, which means that it is not loaded unless it's running on a web server which already has it.

Comment: @Steve do this is for the package phrase.

Comment: @Steve thanks.but it can run with eclipse.for the same configuration,why idea is always wrong,which always report  classnotfundException error.

Comment: I would guess that Eclipse has the Servlet API on its own classpath, whereas Idea needs you to do some configuration of such dependencies yourself. Also, you seem to be trying to run it as an executable jar, so a 'provided' dependency is not appropriate. That's usually only appropriate for people building a war file and deploying that to a web server.

Comment: @Steve if i don't set it as provided,when i package it as war,it wil be wrapped into the war classpath,which will conflict with the container.

Comment: @Steve i will have a try .add a serlet-api jar to the classpath

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to set it as `test`.